# with given output, how many terms are used in the program calculation?

Tags: c++, c, sum

I have the following code which calculates, for the number of terms of your choosing, the square root of 6 * [ 1 + 1/(2^2) + 1/(3^2)....1/(n^2)]. In this case, I'm going with 100 terms. **If I am given what the output should be, is there a way to, using my existing code, determine how many terms were used to get to that output?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    long double square = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        long double squareExp = i*i;
        square += 1/(squareExp);
    }

    long double sixTimes = 6 * square;
    long double squareRoot = sqrt(sixTimes);

    printf("%.8Lf", squareRoot);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried making it so that I take the desired output (3.141592), squaring it and dividing by 6 to negative the square root and (*6), and tried running this code:

```
double temp = 3.141592 * 3.141592;
double tempB = temp / 6;
printf("%f\n", tempB);
int reachedZero = 0;
int valueOfN = 0;

long double square = 0;
while (square > 0) {
    int i = 1;
    square -= 1/i;
    i++;
    if (square <= 1) {
        reachedZero = 1;
        valueOfN = i;
        break;
    }
}

printf("%i", valueOfN);



return 0;
```

}

I can't figure out what to do. I want to take the number (after getting rid of the square root and multiplying by 6), and subtract numbers starting with 1, then 1/4, then 1/9, then 1/16...1/(n^2) until the number becomes negative. Once that happens, I set a flag and I know how many terms I needed to reach that #. I then set that specific counter to a variable, which I can print out.

Comment: So, given a result, you want to get the `n`? How is this reverse engineering? This is maths, look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html

Comment: Actually, this isn't the Harmonic series (the denominator is squared); this is the generalized harmonic series. But [Wolfram Alpha will tell you the answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2Fn%5E2%29)

Comment: @RaymondChen Did I ever say that it is not generalized? The linked article explains gen.HN too.

Comment: @deviantfan My apologies.

Comment: @deviantfan I don't think Raymond was trying to be rude; no need to bring that here. Thanks both for pointing me to articles, but I had already seen them before coming here.

Comment: At some point the results will become indistinguishable. How many digits the "result" has after the decimal point?

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry! I should obviously have specified that. The number has 6 decimal places. The number I'm using as my output is actually pi with 6 decimal places (3.141592). I just don't know where to begin in terms of coding it out and sorting out the logic.

Comment: The naive approach would be to code this function, run it for increasing `n`s and compare to the input. Once it becomes same-or-greater (since you can't compare doubles for strict equality), this is your number.

Comment: @EugeneSh. makes sense...what about an approach that wouldn't be...naive

Comment: Just from the top of my mind - first get rid of the extra stuff - like factor of 6 and square root (by squaring and dividing by six, of course). An then start subtracting terms one by one until crossing zero. Still not a best solution, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

@EugeneSh. This was a working solution for me. Basically matched the pi output I was looking for with my loop, checking it each time. Could have changed the for loop to a while loop but it works fine this way.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    long double square;
    for (long i = 1; i>=1; i++) {
        square += 1.0/(i*i);
        long double sixTimes = sqrt(6 * square);
        if (sixTimes >= 3.141592) {
            printf("%li", i);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```